# Docker image does not run - cannot find module

Tags: typescript, docker, express, apollo-server

I have a docker image of my TypeScript based server, that I was able to build and deploy previouly on Heroku without any problems. There was an minor change in my code that I wanted to push and since then the docker image runs with error as seen in the screenshot below

[image: below]

My dockerfile:

[image: dockerfile]

My package.json:

[image: package.json]

My index.ts:

[image: index.ts]

**Even after undoing those changes in the code and building the original image instead(that worked previously) the issue still persists.**

How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unlikely, that this has anything to do with docker. Did you maybe pick up a newer version of some dependency?

Comment: No I haven't it's the same thing. I even went to the previous commit. Still it didn't work.

Comment: So all dependencies are locked down to exact version numbers?

Comment: Yes the dependencies didn't change.

Comment: In my experience with nodejs I doubt that is not a dependencies issue and that is exactly what you error message suggests. Please share your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` plus the Dockerfile.

Comment: @Exadra37 I have posted the screenshot you asked now by editing the question. check the question now.  I guess there is something problem with the apollo server as that is the only thing in my index.ts and without that there is no error, But the error only appears when running in docker.

Comment: I even created a new project but still it is not working.

Comment: I don't see a package-lock.json file in your project. So the dependency versions are NOT locked down.

Comment: I created a new project even with the package-lock file it doesn't work.

Comment: That's because you need to recreate the version combination that worked some time ago. Now, you get the newest versions compatible with the constraints in `package.json`.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone especially @Henry I tried downgrading the apollo server version and locked it then it works perfectly.